# Firebase not sending push notification to iOS app with bundle starting from anything other than com.xxx.yyy

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, bundle-identifier

I am working on updating my iOS app with BundleID of form **in.xxx.yyy**.
As an update I am adding FCM for sending push notifications to my iOS app. When I try to send sandboxed test notifications from Firebase console by selecting my bundleID, the notifition is never sent. But the same is sent when I target it through FCM token.

Does it create problem if I have an app ID starting with **in** or anything other than **com**, in case of FireBase cloud messaging.

Any view/update on this will be helpful.

Comment: Also I have seen on a tutorial video that, any bundleID starting with anything other than com.xxx.yyy will not receive push notification.

Comment: Anybody having same problem?

Comment: I am not aware of this issue. Be sure to be uploading the right certificates. If the issue persists, please contact https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini : I am sure the certificates uploaded from my side are correct. Incorrect certificates are not accepted by Firebase.